# TicTacToe game, trying to find the winner

Tags: python, indexing, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to find the winner in tic-tac-toe game.
I check the indexes of my list if are equal, but it seems that is doesn't work. Here is the code. When the indexes change with the letter `x` or `o` I want to check if they are equal.

Sorry for this, but I couldn't upload the question because it has too much code.

```
board = ['_','_','_',
         '_','_','_',
         '_','_','_']

player1 = ''
player2 = ''

def board_display ():

    global board
    index_board = ('0','1','2',
                  '3','4','5',
                  '6','7','8 ' )
    #Index Board
    print("Position Board \n{} |{} |{} |\n{} |{} |{} |\n{} |{} |{}| \n".format(index_board[0],index_board[1],index_board[2],index_board[3],index_board[4],index_board[5],index_board[6],index_board[7],index_board[8]))

    #Print The Board
    print("{} |{} |{} |\n{} |{} |{} |\n{} |{} |{} |\n".format(board[0],board[1],board[2],board[3],board[4],board[5],board[6],board[7],board[8]))

def player_symbol_choice ():
    global player1
    global player2
    #Accepatbles Signs
    acceptable_values = ['X','O']
    #Player Input Sign
    player1 = input("Please Choose, X or O \n").upper()
    player2 = ''

    #Check if User Choose Between X or O
    while player1 not in acceptable_values:
        player1 = input("Please Choose Only X or O \n").upper()


    print("Player 1 is " +player1)
    if player1 == 'X':
        player2= 'O'
    elif player1 == 'O':
        player2 = 'X'
    print("Player 2 is " +player2)

def gameplay ():
    print("Select position for your sign between 0 - 8\nYou can check the position board to be sure that your choice is in the place you want")
    #The accepatbles index values
    acceptables_positions = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    #Player 1 Turn
    Turn1 = int(input("Player 1 \nPlease play your move: "))
    #Check if the input values is in the range of 0-8
    while Turn1 not in acceptables_positions:
        Turn1 = int(input("Player 1 \nPlease play your move, between values 0-8: "))
    #Change the index value and replace it with Player 1 sign
    board[Turn1] = player1
    board_display ()

    Turn2 = int(input("Player 2 \nPlease play your move: "))
    while Turn2 not in acceptables_positions:
        Turn2 = int(input("Player 2 \nPlease play your move, between values 0-8: "))
    board[Turn2] = player2

    board_display ()
```

In this function i'm trying to find the winner.

```
 def find_winner():

        if board[0] == board[1] == board[2]:
            print("Player 1 Wins" )
        elif board[3] == board[4] == board[5]:
            print("Player 1 Wins" )

        elif board[6] == board[7] == board[8]:
            print("Player 1 Wins" )

        elif board[0] == board[4] == board[8]:
            print("Player 1 Wins" )

board_display()
player_symbol_choice ()
while True:

    
    gameplay()
    find_winner()
```

Comment: Thought #1: there are 3 rows + 3 columns + 2 diagonals = 8 combinations that can give a win. You seem to only check 4 possible combinations.

Comment: yes i know that, but it doesnt work even if the index0 ,1 and 2 are equals

Comment: Thought #2: Your starting board, consisting of every field having the value "_", will return a winner.

Comment: Yes but down in the code, i replace the empty indexes with X or O. Every time player 1 and player 2 add an input, i want to check if the indexes are equal.

Comment: Your `find_winner()` seem fines, where did you called it?

Comment: In a while True loop.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use the marker.

But this is most likely what you searched for. Got the content from Udemy Course.

Credits @ Jose

Hints and tricks:

https://github.com/Pierian-Data/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp/blob/master/04-Milestone%20Project%20-%201/02-Milestone%20Project%201%20-%20Walkthrough%20Steps%20Workbook.ipynb

Full walkthrough:

https://github.com/Pierian-Data/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp/blob/master/04-Milestone%20Project%20-%201/03-Milestone%20Project%201%20-%20Complete%20Walkthrough%20Solution.ipynb

def win_check(board,mark):

```
return ((board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark) or # across the top
(board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark) or # across the middle
(board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # across the bottom
(board[7] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[1] == mark) or # down the middle
(board[8] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[2] == mark) or # down the middle
(board[9] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # down the right side
(board[7] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # diagonal
(board[9] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[1] == mark)) # diagonal
```

This function takes the actual board and the marker, so you can just call the function after every move and check if the person with X or 0 has won.

Just call checkWin(,<X||0>

Comment: Mark is the variable you are passing with the function. Means if you call the function with 'X' it will check if there are 3 X in a row. So you need to know which Player has X or 0

Comment: Yeah i got it. But check in my code, i think i do the same thing.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve that issue,  my intention was to show you which lines you need to check for. The marker solves the problem that you dont get a winner without the correct filled fields